# Should we lower the flag count for spam/rude-abusive for brand new users and chat flags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, moderator-tools

While we do love our new users - oftentimes spammers are 1 reputation users, simply cause they (clearly) don't get any votes.

While I do realise there's potential for abuse - it feels like a lower flag requirement for post deletion for 1 rep users, say 3 flags with an automatic mod escalation (so we can review) and an automatic posting ban for that class of post until review if a certain threshold of posts is met, say 2 feels like a decent idea.

We want a low barrier to entry *but* I feel like lowering the barrier to getting in trouble for bad behaviour would do a lot to mitigate bigger spam waves, since they'd need to generate more credentials, and its going to rate limit them.

We've had a few recent spam waves this would probably have helped with and it seems a measure that might work with existing tools to get rid of these spam faster.

Comment: What effect would this have on the charcoal project? Would they need to change the way they operate at all?

Comment: I *think* they do 3 flags by default - with some criteria. The autoflag *should* catch false positives they missed - or adjusting the thresholds for a new user might be an option.

Comment: You are correct Journeyman Geek. Most auto flagged posts get 3 flags but if they meet some other criteria they get 4 auto-flags. And with spam waves, if mods of the site approve we make it 6 auto flags for that wave. @Robert Longson As for it affecting. I don't know the code so I cant say but Im sure it cant be too hard to make only 1 flag is cast automatically.